# What is the correct way to nest data within a graphql?

Tags: graphql

I have an address in my database that I've put into a `location` hash. The hash contains separate keys for `streetAddress`, `city`, `state`, and `zipCode`. I've nested the data like so in my graphql schema file:

```
location: {
    streetAddress: { 
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unqiue: true
    },
    city: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }, 
    state: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    zipCode: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
  }
```

And I've implemented the schema type like this:

```
fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    id: {type: GraphQLID},
    phoneNum: { type: GraphQLString },
    location: {
      streetAddress: { type: GraphQLString },
      city: { type: GraphQLString },
      state: { type: GraphQLString },
      zipCode: { type: GraphQLInt }
    }
    ...
```

However, I get an error message saying that the output type is undefined when I try to do a query in graphql:

```
"message": "The type of RestaurantType.location must be Output Type but got: undefined."
```

I believe I understand where the error is coming from; I'm assuming that it expects `location` to have a type as well. What would be the correct syntax for doing this/fixing this error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you guessed, you cannot have nested fields like that. You need to create a separate type for every object in your schema. First create the type:

```
const Location = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Location',
  fields: () => ({
    streetAddress: { type: GraphQLString },
    city: { type: GraphQLString },
    state: { type: GraphQLString },
    zipCode: { type: GraphQLInt }
  }),
})
```

Then use it:

```
const Restaurant = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Restaurant',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    location: { type: Location },
  }),
})
```

or if you don't need to reuse the type, you can define it inline like this:

```
const Restaurant = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Restaurant',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    location: {
      type: new GraphQLObjectType({
        name: 'Location',
        fields: () => ({
          streetAddress: { type: GraphQLString },
          city: { type: GraphQLString },
          state: { type: GraphQLString },
          zipCode: { type: GraphQLInt }
        }),
      })
    },
  }),
})
```

Comment: Ah ok, so no nested fields. So from your example, it looks like I can still break out the location data into a separate constant, is that correct? It makes sense, for the sake of organization.

Comment: Yes, if you want to inline it instead if you want, as long as you don't need to reuse the type elsewhere. See the edited answer for an example.

Comment: Ah ok, this is awesome! Thanks for the clarification!